# Alphabetical bibliography using .bib file and .bbl file

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I am using .bst file for my bibliography in latex. I sort my references in a .bib file and I put the in alphabetical order as follows:

```
    @article{Abdi2015,
    author = {Abdi, H. and Labrie, D. and Nguyen, T.S. and Barnichon, J.D. and Su, G. and Evgin, E. and Simon, R. and Fall, M.},
    title = {Laboratory investigation on the mechanical behaviour of Tournemire argillite},
    journal = {Canadian Geotechnical Journal},
    volume = {52},
    number = {},
    pages = {268-282},
    year = {2015}
}

@article{Addetta2002,
    author = {D'addetta, G.~A. and Kun, F. and Ramm E.},
    title = {On the application of a discrete model to the fracture process of cohesive granular materials},
    journal = {Granular matter},
    volume = {4},
    number = {2},
    pages = {77-90},
    year = {2002}
}

@article{Anders2014,
    author = {Anders, M.~H. and Laubach, S.~E. and Scholz, C.~H.},
    title = {Microfractures: A review},
    journal = {Journal of Structural Geology},
    volume = {693},
    number = {1-3},
    pages = {477-394},
    year = {2014},
}

@article{Asadi2012,
    author = {Asadi, M.~S. and Rasouli, V. and Barla, G.},
    title = {A Bonded Particle Model Simulation of Shear Strength and Asperity Degradation for Rough Rock Fractures},
    journal = {Journal of Rock Mechanics and Rock Engineering},
    volume = {45},
    number = {1-4},
    pages = {649-675},
    year = {2012},
}

@article{Bidgoli2013,
    author = {Noorian~Bidgoli, M. and Zhao, Z. and Jing, L.},
    title = {Numerical evaluation of strength and deformability of fractured rocks},
    journal = {Journal of rock mechanics and geotechnical engineering},
    volume = {5},
    number = {5},
    pages = {419-430},
    year = {2013}
}

@article{Bidgoli2014,
    author = {Noorian~Bidgoli, M. and Jing, L.},
    title = {Anisotropy of strength and deformability of fractured rocks},
    journal = {Journal of rock mechanics and geotechnical engineering},
    volume = {6},
    number = {5},
    pages = {156-164},
    year = {2014},
}

@article{Blake2016,
    author = {Blake, O.~O. and Faulkner, D.~R.},
    title = {The effect of fracture density and stress state on the static and dynamic bulk moduli of Westerly granite},
    journal = {Journal of Geophysical Research - Solid Earth},
    volume = {121},
    number = {},
    pages = {2382–2399},
    year = {2016},
}

@article{Chan1970,
    author = {Chan, S.~K. and Tuba, I.~S. and Wilson, W.~K.},
    title = {On the finite element method in linear fracture mechanics},
    journal = {Engineering fracture mechanics},
    volume = {2},
    number = {1},
    pages = {1-17},
    year = {1970}
}
```

But my references do not show in alphabetical order and they show randomly in my .bbl file which eventually appear in .pdf file random as well something like this:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{29}
\expandafter\ifx\csname natexlab\endcsname\relax\def\natexlab#1{#1}\fi
\providecommand{\bibinfo}[2]{#2}
\ifx\xfnm\relax \def\xfnm[#1]{\unskip,\space#1}\fi
%Type = Article
\bibitem[{Asadi et~al.(2012)Asadi, Rasouli, and Barla}]{Asadi2012}
\bibinfo{author}{M.~S. Asadi}, \bibinfo{author}{V.~Rasouli},
  \bibinfo{author}{G.~Barla},
\newblock \bibinfo{title}{A bonded particle model simulation of shear strength
  and asperity degradation for rough rock fractures},
\newblock \bibinfo{journal}{Journal of Rock Mechanics and Rock Engineering}
  \bibinfo{volume}{45} (\bibinfo{year}{2012}) \bibinfo{pages}{649--675}.
%Type = Article
\bibitem[{Fu and Evans(1985)}]{Fu1985}
\bibinfo{author}{Y.~Fu}, \bibinfo{author}{G.~Evans},
\newblock \bibinfo{title}{Some effects of microcracks on the mechanical
  properties of brittle solids-i. stress, strain relations},
\newblock \bibinfo{journal}{Acta Metallurgica} \bibinfo{volume}{33}
  (\bibinfo{year}{1985}) \bibinfo{pages}{1515--1523}.
%Type = Article
\bibitem[{Anders et~al.(2014)Anders, Laubach, and Scholz}]{Anders2014}
\bibinfo{author}{M.~H. Anders}, \bibinfo{author}{S.~E. Laubach},
  \bibinfo{author}{C.~H. Scholz},
\newblock \bibinfo{title}{Microfractures: A review},
\newblock \bibinfo{journal}{Journal of Structural Geology}
  \bibinfo{volume}{693} (\bibinfo{year}{2014}) \bibinfo{pages}{477--394}.
%Type = Article
\bibitem[{Noorian~Bidgoli and Jing(2014)}]{Bidgoli2014}
\bibinfo{author}{M.~Noorian~Bidgoli}, \bibinfo{author}{L.~Jing},
\newblock \bibinfo{title}{Anisotropy of strength and deformability of fractured
  rocks},
\newblock \bibinfo{journal}{Journal of rock mechanics and geotechnical
  engineering} \bibinfo{volume}{6} (\bibinfo{year}{2014})
  \bibinfo{pages}{156--164}.
%Type = Article
\bibitem[{Simmons and Richter(1976)}]{Simmons1976}
\bibinfo{author}{G.~Simmons}, \bibinfo{author}{D.~Richter},
\newblock \bibinfo{title}{Microcracks in rock},
\newblock \bibinfo{journal}{The Physics and Chemistry of Minerals and Rocks}
  (\bibinfo{year}{1976}) \bibinfo{pages}{105--137}.
%Type = Article
\bibitem[{Noorian~Bidgoli et~al.(2013)Noorian~Bidgoli, Zhao, and
  Jing}]{Bidgoli2013}
\bibinfo{author}{M.~Noorian~Bidgoli}, \bibinfo{author}{Z.~Zhao},
  \bibinfo{author}{L.~Jing},
\newblock \bibinfo{title}{Numerical evaluation of strength and deformability of
  fractured rocks},
\newblock \bibinfo{journal}{Journal of rock mechanics and geotechnical
  engineering} \bibinfo{volume}{5} (\bibinfo{year}{2013})
  \bibinfo{pages}{419--430}.
```

It seems that the references are being sorted in order of citation in the text! Is there any type of citation that would put my references in alphabetical order despite in what order they are being cited in the text?

I cite them as `cite{}`.
How should I cite them for an alphabetical order?
Thanks a bunch

Comment: Which `.bst` file do you use? The `.bst` file determines sorting. Can you show a full [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) of your document that shows which bibliography packages and style you use?

Comment: @moewe, I am using model1-num-names.bst which is an standard package of elsevier (elsarticle.cls), this is what I use \bibliographystyle{model1-num-names}. What exactly do you need to know? Although as I edited my question it seems it has something to do with the order of citation! The references appear in the order they are cited in the text and not in alphabetical order! any idea what I should do with that?

Comment: Are you submitting to an Elsevier journal? In that case you probably should not change their `.bst` files. Only use the file for the journal you submit to.

Comment: @moewe, yeah that's what I am doing, but besides that my questions stands still, is it because of the type of citation that it shows this way?

Comment: It is because the `.bst` style you use sorts references by citation order. Other styles may well sort alphabetically by author name, but of the Elsevier styles I found only the author-year styles do this, the numeric styles all sort by citation order.

Comment: Is there any news here?

Comment: @Johannes_B , Hey what's up?

Comment: @moewe, is there a function in bst file to specify the sorting method? I mean, in general, in any bst file, the sorting is determined by a function so that I can open my bst file and check what is happening there?

Comment: @Sigur BibTeX has a built-in command called `SORT` that probably all styles that apply sorting call at some point. `SORT` sorts the entries according to the value of their `sort.key$`. Traditionally the value of `sort.key$` is assigned in a function called `presort` or similar that is called just before `SORT`. Usually `presort` calls a chain of other functions, so that it can take a while to untangle the exact sorting behaviour, but it can often give you a first idea. Initially all entries are in citation order and if there is no `SORT` that is the order in which they are written out.

Comment: @moewe, thanks for attention. I am using a Brazilian bst which has 2 formats: `num` and `alf`. What I'd like is to have the `num` style, but in alphabetical order, that is, numbered in alphabetical order. I'm trying to see if I can do this or if I should contact the guys who created that.

Comment: @Sigur It might be possible to just transplant the sort stuff from `alf` to `num`, but depending on how exactly `alf` works and sorts that might not be the greatest idea. If the general bibliography output is sufficiently similar you can run a diff on the two files and that might already give you an idea what to copy and where. (But of course the real answer is to use `biblatex` ;-) Though given that you are talking about Brazilian styles only if it's not ABNT.)

Comment: @moewe, unfortunately, it is from ABNT. I'm using the style they provide, but I am going to change and break the rules, since numerical and non alphabetical sort is too bad.

Comment: @Sigur I'm sorry to hear that you have to endure ABNT. I personally don't think unsorted numeric is worse than alphabetically sorted numeric. If the `alf` style does not  actually sort by (full) names, title and year (or a sensible variation thereof), but instead by the alphabetic label [SR98], then I would even say it is worse (see also my rant about alph-sorting in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/472951/35864).

Comment: @moewe, the `alf` style sort by full names, but what I don't like is to have the `[SR98]` instead of the numbers `[1], [2],...`

Comment: @moewe, the only non comment difference between them is: `"$RCSfile: abnt-num.bst,v $ " extract.cvs.key` and `"$RCSfile: abnt-alf.bst,v $ " extract.cvs.key`. So I'll try to edit the num file and change this line to see if the sort changes to alphabetical.

Comment: @Sigur The versions of the files I found do some very clever things. It looks as though their source code is exactly the same save for that one bit. If you want to have allphabetic sorting in the numeric style you will have to manipulate `presort` from the looks of it.

Comment: @moewe, thanks. I'll take a look at `presort`. Probably I'm not able to edit but lets see...